# Create an apk from a PWA that's on an intranet

Tags: apk, progressive-web-apps, intranet

We have a PWA that is hosted internally and not accessible from the outside world.

We need to convert it into an APK to host it on our company internal store.

The issue is that the tools i found try to access the PWA via the internet and thus cannot because it is only on our intranet.
Mainly they ask for the URL of the manifest

How could we do it ?

This is a vuejs application if it is of any importance

Comment: Have you checked the PWA Google tutorial? It seems that it does not rely on online generators, instead it uses a local toll called "Bubblewrap", so you could execute it in your internal network: https://developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-in-play#0

Comment: Ive try bubblewrap but i get 401 downloading the manifest (you have to provide an url for this tool)